# Explode date ranges in SQL to individual boolean day rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider I have the following table:

```
entry       exit
2017-05-12  2017-05-15
2017-05-19  2017-05-19
2017-05-21  2017-06-25
2017-06-29  2017-07-22
```

Using SQL, I want to explode this into rows, where each row represents a day and whether this day is inside any of the ranges. For example:

```
day        is_inside
2017-05-12 true
2017-05-13 true
2017-05-14 true
2017-05-15 true
2017-05-16 false
2017-05-17 false
2017-05-18 false
2017-05-19 true
2017-05-20 false
2017-05-21 true
...
```

You can consider that the ranges do not overlap.

Comment: please tag the database being used.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `generate_series` to generate the dates between specified start and end period. Then the table can be `left join`ed to this to generate the desired result.

```
select t.dt,tbl.entry is null as is_inside
from generate_series('2018-05-12'::date,'2018-05-19','1 day') t(dt) --change the date range as needed
left join tbl on t.dt>=tbl.entry and t.dt<=tbl.exit
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `generate_series()`.  Assuming the periods do not overlap:

```
select gs.dte, (t.entry is not null) as is_inside
from (select generate_series(min_entry, max_exit, interval '1 day) gs(dte)
      from (select min(entry) as min_entry, max(exit) as max_exit
            from t
           ) t
     ) gs left join
     t
     on gs.dte >= t.entry and gs.dte <= t.exit;
```

Two notes:

- In more recent versions of Postgres, I would use a lateral join rather than subquery for the `generate_series()`.
- If you do have overlaps, then use `exists` in the `select` rather than `left join`.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you have a date table (tally table for dates). If you don't, search for date tables and create one. It is basically a table with one row for each date, and it lets you easily do queries on date ranges. A lot of date tables have a lot of other columns, but for this purpose you just need the date column. You can create a temporary date table for running the query if you need to. Example [search result](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112548/how-to-create-date-table).

Then you can query that table for the date range you care about, and try to left outer join to the date range table - if you get a join then it is true, else it is false. Something like this (this may not be exact postgres syntax, I'm rusty on it, but the theory is the same)

```
Select DT.Date, CASE WHEN DR.entry IS NULL THEN 'true' else 'false' end as is_inside
From DateTable DT 
    left outer join DateRange DR on DT.Date between DR.entry and DR.exit
Where DT.Date  ... (date range to report)
```

If you did possibly have overlapping ranges, all you would need to to do is distinct the results - you will only ever have one false or (one or more) true results.